# Why was my question about breakpoints in eclipse marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8748070/664577) about the inability to set breakpoints on a project was marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2415655/664577) about the inability to set break points over a specific class.

All the symptoms are different (diagonal line vs normal breakpoints / project vs class, etc). Also my answer was accepted and is still receiving upvotes one year and a half later. The question marked as duplicate is 3.5 year old and have no accepted answers.

Comment: Looks like a moderator mistake. Happens sometimes. I'm not going to cast a vote, because I don't know Java well enough to judge, but this will probably be resolved soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question, as well as a couple of others, came to our attention when a user posted some exact duplicate answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16117307) (target question), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16117273) (deleted; question marked as duplicate), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16117229) (deleted; question marked as duplicate). Those were the ones I found after a quick glance.

It was likely just an oversight. The community has reopened the question for you and all is well.